# ERROR:Type: ArgumentCountError, Too few arguments to function

Tags: php, codeigniter

It happens that I am showing some data from my database through some Foreach, in which I am using echo to display the value of each field that I require. So far I have used in my query sql, in the condition of WHERE any value that I throw a result to show it, however this I must do it by means of some variable, in this case would be $ rut_usu, that will store the selected rut from a select (listboxt) in the view. But when adding in the model, in the sql query my variable (which still has no value, because I have not selected any value from the listboxt) throws me the following error:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: ArgumentCountError

Message: Too few arguments to function M_Calendar::monday(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\application\controllers\C_Calendar.php on line 23 and exactly 1 expected

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\application\models\M_Calendar.php

Line Number: 106

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\application\controllers\C_Calendar.php
Line: 23
Function: monday

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

What would be the solution for this? Should I do what I require in some other way?

I leave my code:

Controller:

```
   public function index(){


    $this->load->view('layouts/Header.php');
    $this->load->view('layouts/Menu.php');
    $this->load->model('M_Calendar');
    $data['monday'] = $this->M_Calendar->monday();
    $data['tuesday'] = $this->M_Calendar->tuesday(); 
    $data['Wednesday'] = $this->M_Calendar->wednesday();
    $data['thursday'] = $this->M_Calendar->thursday();
    $data['friday'] = $this->M_Calendar->friday();  
    $data['saturday'] = $this->M_Calendar->saturday();
    $data['usuarios'] = $this->M_Calendar->get_usuarios();

    $this->load->view('usuarios/V_Consulta_Horarios.php',$data);
    $this->load->view('layouts/Footer.php');

   }
```

Model (I have several functions like this, from Monday to Saturday)

```
  public function  monday($rut_usu){


 $this->db->select('MIN(horario.hrs_ini) AS hrs_ini, MAX(horario.hrs_ter) AS hrs_ter ');
 $this->db->from('horario');
 $this->db->join('usuarios','horario.rut_usu = usuarios.rut_usu');
 $this->db->where('usuarios.rut_usu',$rut_usu); 
 $this->db->where('horario.lunes','ATTE. ESTUDIANTES');
 $this->db->where('fecha_registro = (SELECT MAX(fecha_registro) FROM horario)');
 $this->db->limit('14');
 $monday = $this->db->get();


if($monday->num_rows() > 0 ){

 return $monday->result();

  }

}
```

The variables I am showing them inside a javascript using fullcalendar, which as I mentioned before worked well

```
businessHours: [ // specify an array instea
{
dow: [ 1], // Monday

<?php foreach($monday as $row){?>
   start: '<?php  $inicio= "00:00"; $start1_ok = $row->hrs_ini;

if (empty($start1_ok)) { echo $inicio;}

else { echo $start1_ok;} ?>', 
end: '<?php echo $row->hrs_ter ;?>' 
<?php }?>

 },
```

Comment: You need to pass the user rut into the function, you are calling the function with no parameters, and the function expects at least this parameter `$rut_usu`

Comment: Of course, but how could I do this without making me mistake? since I need to display the values from the database, but they must be displayed once filtered

Comment: Have you read this line ? Message: Too few arguments to function `M_Calendar::monday()`, **0** passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\application\controllers\C_Calendar.php on line 23 and exactly **1** expected

Comment: read the comment I wrote above, I know why it happens, I do not know how to correct it

Comment: What would be the solution for this? Should I do what I require in some other way?

Comment: That should be easy man, once the user gets logged in, you need to store the user rut into a session and then just use that rut...switching to spanish...eres de Chile por casualidad xD

Comment: It is not the user's that should be displayed, if not the one that is selected XD Si, soy de Chile XD